# Olympus XZ-1 or Lumix LX5?

Tags: point-and-shoot, camera-recommendation, panasonic, olympus

I wonder which one of the two cameras should I get. [Here](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/37582/olympus-zx-1-vs-panasonic-lx5) is one comparison. I've seen good photos on flickr using both cameras, so I'm not sure. People say that the Lumix's aperture is slower than the Olympus.
EDIT:
Also, is it possible on the Olympus to disable the bokkeh effect?

Comment: You linked an review comparing those exact two cameras against each other...what else are you expecting us to say that hasn't been covered by that review?  "People say that the Lumix's aperture is slower" because it *is slower* from an optical/physics standpoint, its not a judgement call.

Comment: I expect some comments about the cameras from owners or people who used them.

Comment: For questions like these, it's really helpful to know what your level of experience is, and how you intend to use the camera.  Bonus points for stuff like "I've got [x], and I'm upgrading because I want a camera that's better at [y]."  In lieu of this sort of personalized scenario, we're really just trying to take the place of a review site, which won't work especially well in this format.

Comment: I have Canon sd780, which is a great point-and-shoot. I'm a newbie on photography and I saw that the LX5 and XZ-1 make awesome photos, and they're both pretty small.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "disable the bokeh effect", but assuming you mean you want more of the photo in sharp focus, see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/how-to-get-more-of-the-photo-in-focus

Comment: @blez - Ok, so what is it about the Canon sd780 you hope to improve upon?

Comment: @D. Lambert: The macro and night shots.

Comment: @blez - I think if you put all the stuff you've added in comments into your question, you'd have a question that might yield more answers that are better-tailored to your specific needs.  I'd even vote it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *bokeh* is influenced by the aperture you choose. It is not an effect.

The wider the aperture you choose, the less depth-of-field you get which is what makes bokeh appear. With the Olympus you have more latitude to choose less depth-of-field but you can choose an equally large depth-of-field on both camera.

The Olympus ZX-1 is really nice and produce very good quality images for its class. It also handles very well because of its well-placed dials. I'd go for the ZX-1 except if ultra-wide-angle is very important for you.