# How do I take an image without a blurry background?

Tags: depth-of-field, blur, hyperfocal-distance

I'm very new to DSLRs and I was wondering how to make it so that my Nikon D3300 focuses but does not blur anything out like when it focuses on a flower or something and it blurs everything else around it. I have been trying to figure it out but with no luck.

Comment: Possibly see: [How can I take a photo with everything in focus with my DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30976) and [How do I get adequate depth of field in macro photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22358).

Comment: Try selecting higher apertures (towards f22) or google "focus stacking" if you have a tripod and a photo-editing software

Comment: @Noldor130884 Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge

Comment: @MichaelClark don't want to argue about that, but without any background information, my comment doesn't "qualify" to be an answer. Besides, if it was, I would have added tons of informations

Comment: @Noldor130884 Which is how this is supposed to work. When you put an answer out there it can be voted up, voted down, and improved. When you put information (rather than ask for clarification from the OP or point to the needed information in another existing question/answer) in a comment it will just eventually be deleted and does no one any good.

Comment: @Noldor130884 The appropriate way to do what perhaps you attempted would be to search this site for articles regarding using narrower aperture or focus stacking and provide links to that information *here at photo.stackexchange*, rather than just suggest someone "google" something.

Comment: @MichaelClark Sure, but do you realize that there is absolutely no background information that comes from the question? I'm sure you do. It's impossible to answer a question like this one and be precise enough to fulfill the expectations of the one who asked it

Comment: @Noldor130884 Which means it is even more futile to try and answer it in a 19-word comment that no one else can edit or downvote. Either link several other related questions/answers here at photo.stackexchange or put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like with any other camera you stop it down to a small aperture like f/22, say, of course it depends on the background distance as well. If you go that high, though, you will get light diffraction which will be apparent. 
The larger the aperture the shallower the depth of field; that is why big apertures like f/1.8 and f/1.4 are usually used for portraits to separate the subject from the background and give a nice bokeh.