# How to achieve large DOF in a macro like this video?

Tags: focus, depth-of-field, field-of-view

I noticed that this video has a very beautiful DOF, almost spot on. It is a video but should still be applicable to photography. So how is such precise and large Depth of field achieved? What kind of lend can be used on an SLR?

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wKu13wmHog)

Comment: Have you read the numerous depth of field examples on this site, for example [How do I get adequate depth of field in macro photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22358/how-do-i-get-adequate-depth-of-field-in-macro-photography) and [What exactly determines depth of field?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9624/what-exactly-determines-depth-of-field). If so, what about the subject do you still not understand?

Comment: i don't see a large DOF in this video, it looks rather shallow, as is expected?

Comment: It has a great focus, but no _depth of focus_. Are you sure you understand the term?

Comment: Calling depth of field "spot on" and "precise" doesn't make sense to me. I think you are confusing focus with depth of field.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with others that the DOF is not very large on the video.  Understand that the longer the telephoto focal length is, the shorter the DOF will be.  A large lens opening will also reduce DOF.  sot to increase DOF use a lens that tends toward normal or wide angle and a small (large number like f16) F stop. If using a telephoto lens so you don't have to get close, you may be able to use motion tracking focus to keep the subject in focus.